# Ansible: How to write a service-centric inventory?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Ansible usually works host-centric: If you have a host with some host variables in more than one group in an inventory then all variables for that host will be merged and those with the same name overwrite each other. Example:

```
# Inventory

[app_stages:children]
stage_development
stage_acceptance

[stage_development]
localhost db_unique_name=scdev oracle_version_db=12.1.0.2 oracle_edition_db=SE2
localhost db_unique_name=ecdev oracle_version_db=12.1.0.2 oracle_edition_db=EE

[stage_acceptance]
localhost db_unique_name=scacp oracle_version_db=18 oracle_edition_db=SE2
localhost db_unique_name=ecacp oracle_version_db=18 oracle_edition_db=EE
```

```
# Playbook
- name: test inventory
  hosts: "{{ hostgroup }}"

  tasks:
    - name: show variables
      debug:
        msg: host {{ ansible_hostname }}, db_name = {{ db_unique_name }}, db_version = {{ oracle_version_db }}, db_edition = {{ oracle_edition_db }}
```

Result:

```
   ansible-playbook playbook_1.yml -i inventory_1 -e hostgroup=stage_development

   TASK [show variables]  ******************************************************************************************************************
   ok: [localhost] => {
       "msg": "host server_1, db_name = ecacp, db_version = 18, db_edition = EE"
   }
```

This shows even if I request ansible to work on stage_development only it uses and displays the variables set in the other group.

I need a different approach: Primarily I want to specify services with some essential parameters (e.g. database Name, version and so on, see above). Whether or not some or all of them shall be deployed to the same host is secondary. This one works but is not so elegant because the informations about the services are in the playbook and not in the inventory which should be generated by some external tool (CMS) later:

```
# Inventory
[app_stages:children]
stage_development
stage_acceptance

[stage_development:children]
srv_scdev
srv_ecdev

[stage_acceptance:children]
srv_scacp
srv_ecacp

[srv_scdev]
localhost

[srv_ecdev]
localhost

[srv_scacp]
localhost

[srv_ecacp]
localhost
```

```
# Playbook
---

- name: stage development, setup database scdev
  hosts: srv_scdev
  vars:
    db_unique_name: scdev
    oracle_version_db: 12.1.0.2
    oracle_edition_db: SE2
  tasks:
    - name: show variables
      debug:
        msg: host {{ ansible_hostname }}, db_name = {{ db_unique_name }}, db_version = {{ oracle_version_db }}, db_edition = {{ oracle_edition_db }}

- name: stage development, setup database ecdev
  hosts: srv_ecdev
  vars:
    db_unique_name: ecdev
    oracle_version_db: 12.1.0.2
    oracle_edition_db: EE
  tasks:
    - name: show variables
      debug:
        msg: host {{ ansible_hostname }}, db_name = {{ db_unique_name }}, db_version = {{ oracle_version_db }}, db_edition = {{ oracle_edition_db }}

- name: stage acceptance, setup database scacp
  hosts: srv_scacp
  vars:
    db_unique_name: scacp
    oracle_version_db: 18
    oracle_edition_db: SE2
  tasks:
    - name: show variables
      debug:
        msg: host {{ ansible_hostname }}, db_name = {{ db_unique_name }}, db_version = {{ oracle_version_db }}, db_edition = {{ oracle_edition_db }}

- name: stage acceptance, setup database ecacp
  hosts: srv_ecacp
  vars:
    db_unique_name: ecacp
    oracle_version_db: 18
    oracle_edition_db: EE
  tasks:
    - name: show variables
      debug:
        msg: host {{ ansible_hostname }}, db_name = {{ db_unique_name }}, db_version = {{ oracle_version_db }}, db_edition = {{ oracle_edition_db }}

...
```

Question: How to do it right/reusable/elegant?

Answer (score 1):

A solution with minimal change would be to extend your inventory with the setting of `ansible_host` and introducing a fake name for the inventory itself like

```
# Inventory

[app_stages:children]
stage_development
stage_acceptance

[stage_development]
dev1 ansible_host=localhost db_unique_name=scdev oracle_version_db=12.1.0.2 oracle_edition_db=SE2
dev2 ansible_host=localhost db_unique_name=ecdev oracle_version_db=12.1.0.2 oracle_edition_db=EE

[stage_acceptance]
stage1 ansible_host=localhost db_unique_name=scacp oracle_version_db=18 oracle_edition_db=SE2
stage2 ansible_host=localhost db_unique_name=ecacp oracle_version_db=18 oracle_edition_db=EE
```